# Reloading jQuery AJAX duplicates JSON output results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

**Summary**

I am trying to loop through a JSON result which is being returned by a CORS AJAX call. The AJAX call needs to refresh every xxx seconds due to it being a constant stream of live data.

**Code Sample**

```
var seconds = 2000; // time in milliseconds
var reload = function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: streamUrl,
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
         for (var i in data) {
               $("#stream").append("<div class='post'><div class='streamText'>" + data[i].keymessage + "</div>" + "<div class='streamUser'>" + data[i].username + "</div></div>")
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                reload();
            }, seconds);
        }
    });
 };
 reload();
```

**Issue**

The sample code provided does refresh the code, however, it simply stacks the new refreshed along with the old results above the previous old results. I need it to refresh the old results with new.

**Example of Issue**

Results Before Reload

```
Bob: Hello
Steve: Hey Bob
```

Results After Reload

```
Sarah: Whats up guys
Bob: Hello
Steve: Hey Bob
Bob: Hello
Steve: Hey Bob
```

Results After Reload (What I need it to do.)

```
Sarah: Whats up guys
Bob: Hello
Steve: Hey Bob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: only one line changes, but because you are appending it just keeps appending your new code. At the start of the loop remove the contents of the stream id element.

That way it removes previous items and allows you to add new items. When call is made again it will repeat itself.

```
 success: function(data) {
                 $("#stream").html("");
                 for (var i in data) {
                       $("#stream").append("<div class='post'><div class='streamText'>" + data[i].keymessage + "</div>" + "<div class='streamUser'>" + data[i].username + "</div></div>")
                    }
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        reload();
                    }, seconds);
                }
            });
```